# NewRelic.so breaks image generation in PHP

Tags: php, image, newrelic

I have a simple function that outputs an image from Google Charts and outputs it as an image to the browser to be passed to Twilo (our SMS provider.)

```
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    $this->layout = false;
    $this->render(false);

    $img = file_get_contents('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=330x330&chl=' . $key . '&chld=H|1');

    echo $img;
```

This has worked great for months. I installed New Relic for server monitoring, and when newrelic.so is added to my PHP.ini it causes this to not execute properly. Basically it dumps the value for the image as opposed to generating the image (much like when I have GZip enabled..)

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug based on your description, you aren't doing anything too out of the ordinary. My guess is that it's trying to do some kind of javascript injection. You can always try another monitoring product, for example AppDynamics.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a conflict with the Javascript insertion for the Browser monitoring feature. This is enabled by default. I would be worthwhile to verify this by disabling the feature in your newrelic.ini file by setting

[newrelic.browser_monitoring.auto_instrument=0](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/features/page-load-timing-php)

If this allows your image to be displayed, then you can disable this for that page only by changing the setting above to '1' and including the New Relic PHP API call

[newrelic_disable_autorum()](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-api#api-rum-disable)

where that page is created.